# D3.request - get JSON from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, d3.js

Have a php code selecting from SQL with "echo json_encode($array);" at the end.

Want to build a graph on D3.js, so I need to get that JSON from php.
How to make it with D3.request() or d3.json() or other? Please, help me with example.
(Here is guide, but I cant make it yet - https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json)

AJAX request is simple:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_json.php",
    data: "FirstName="+ name, //here is the parameter

    success: function(data){
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        alert(data.Content);
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work unless this php file is hosted by a web server. Which you can setup a simple web server with `php -S localhost:8080` if you have php installed. Better documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0):

In order for your javascript code to access the php script it will need to be run on a web server. A simple way to run a web server if you have PHP installed is:

1. Open command line
2. Navigate to the directory with this javascript file and your `get_json.php` file
3. Run the command `php -S localhost:8080`

Now your files are running on a local php web server which allows you to reach the file containing your AJAX request at: `localhost:8080/[ajax js file]`

Comment: I have a php running (on same server). My question is how to use new functions provided by D3 lib ( d3.request() or d3.json() or ? ), to get json from php without jQuery. - https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json

Answer (score 0):

```
var par = 23
d3.json("get_data2.php?par=" + par, function(error, json) {
              if (error) return console.warn(error);
              data = json;
    });
```

solved.